# How do I prevent certain characters from messing up spacing in terminal emacs, nano, etc in WSL2?

Tags: terminal, fonts, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal, line-spacing

Consider the file

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin non
velit sem. Fusce rhoncus eros eget mi blandit, in ultricies mi
sollicitudin. Nam nec justo sollicitudin, varius dolor ut, dapibus
neque. Nulla pharetra aliquet augue at facilisis. Proin efficitur
metus sed condimentum ornare. Quisque condimentum tortor a neque
egestas, a rhoncus orci efficitur. Donec commodo dui lacus. Vivamus
tempor ligula sit amet libero lacinia rutrum.

Nam rutrum finibus elit placerat varius. Suspendisse rutrum non purus
ut tempus. Aliquam commodo eget enim varius eleifend. Curabitur
tincidunt nibh nec rhoncus gravida. Nulla tempor ultricies dolor, eu
lacinia urna sagittis non. Pellentesque at sagittis ante. Aenean
rutrum libero sapien, in fermentum neque sagittis a. Nulla interdum
rhoncus aliquam. Suspendisse ac ante in sem rhoncus
condimentum. Pellentesque accumsan elit vitae condimentum
fermentum. Mauris mollis at mauris ut viverra. Integer ultrices enim
eu lobortis venenatis. Suspendisse vitae ipsum ut nunc vestibulum
consequat in quis enim. Aliquam et molestie enim. Sed iaculis, metus
sit amet sollicitudin congue, lacus nisi cursus ex, in aliquet urna
purus non urna.


Nam elementum bibendum imperdiet. Curabitur euismod augue non elit
laoreet, vel ultricies mauris pellentesque. Pellentesque eu odio vel
turpis finibus placerat. Nullam placerat ante vitae pretium
pulvinar. Donec ut lacus eget ex semper lobortis id at justo. Cras
mollis mi lorem. Ut nisi magna, tincidunt eu eros id, consequat
bibendum libero. Donec gravida nec mauris et mattis. Phasellus et arcu
cursus, tempus purus in, molestie ex. Pellentesque congue elit ac
congue convallis. Vivamus auctor fringilla porttitor. Quisque
tincidunt molestie quam eget elementum. Maecenas imperdiet tortor sit
amet elementum placerat. Aenean gravida mauris sed enim faucibus,
vitae mattis augue dapibus. Proin interdum libero eleifend eros porta
pharetra.
```

where the  is 0x1D7F7 i.e., "MATHEMATICAL MONOSPACE DIGIT ONE".

If I open the above file with a normal `1`, in nano, I see the expected text:
[image: normal text in nano]
If I open the file with the mathematical monospace digit one, I see an extra space at the beginning of the next line:
[image: bad text in nano]
Even more strangely, when I bring the cursor to that line, moving the cursor horizontally to the right seems to move each character one space to the left, even though I'm only pressing arrow keys:
[image: nano misbehaving]
Even more annoyingly, if the line is right before the emacs status bar, then the entire emacs window gets messed up:
Instead of this (with normal `1`s):
[image: good emacs]
I see:
[image: bad emacs]
Note that the "File" menu is gone, and the separator bar at the bottom has wrapped onto the next line.

How do I configure WSL2 / terminal to not mess up the spacing for this character?